# Calculate TF-IDF in WEKA API for single document to predict classification

Tags: java, weka, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

For some reason I am using the WEKA API...

I have generated tf-idf scores for a set of documents,

```
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
filter.setInputFormat(data);
filter.setIDFTransform(true);
filter.setStopwordsHandler(new StopWordsHandlerEN());//just a simple handler for stop words I created
filter.setLowerCaseTokens(true);
filter.setStemmer(new MyStemmer());//a stemmer I created
filter.setWordsToKeep(words2keep);
Instances result = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
```

then split them into train and test subsets, did training, testing and all that...

Once I had a trained ready-to-go model for classification I wanted to create a plain API that would classify any incoming document. But the thing is the new tf-idf scores need to be calculated based on the tf-idf vector and the words of the starting set of documents, right? In other words, if I am not mistaken, I need to load a counterpart of the scikit-learn's `tfidfvectorizer`.

I cannot find anything like it in WEKA... Is there?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [StringToWordVector](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) filter uses the [weka.core.DictionaryBuilder](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/DictionaryBuilder.html) class under the hood for the TF/IDF computation.

As long as you create a `weka.core.Instance` object with the text that you want to have converted, you can do that using the builder's `vectorizeInstance(Instance)` method.

**Edit 1:**

Below is an example based on your code (but with Weka classes), which shows how to either use the filter or the DictionaryBuilder for the TF/IDF transformation. Both get serialized, deserialized and re-used as well to demonstrate that these classes are serializable:

```java
import weka.core.DictionaryBuilder;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.SerializationHelper;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils;
import weka.core.stemmers.LovinsStemmer;
import weka.core.stopwords.Rainbow;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector;

public class TFIDF {

  // just exposes the internal DictionaryBuilder member
  public static class StringToWordVectorExposed
    extends StringToWordVector {

    public DictionaryBuilder getDictionary() {
      return m_dictionaryBuilder;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // load data
    Instances train = ConverterUtils.DataSource.read("/some/where/train.arff");
    train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);
    Instances test = ConverterUtils.DataSource.read("/some/where/test.arff");
    test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes() - 1);
    // init filter
    StringToWordVectorExposed filter = new StringToWordVectorExposed();
    int words2keep = 100;
    filter.setInputFormat(train);
    filter.setIDFTransform(true);
    filter.setStopwordsHandler(new Rainbow());
    filter.setLowerCaseTokens(true);
    filter.setStemmer(new LovinsStemmer());
    filter.setWordsToKeep(words2keep);
    filter.setInputFormat(train);
    Instances trainFiltered = Filter.useFilter(train, filter);
    DictionaryBuilder builder = filter.getDictionary();
    // apply filter/dictionary
    Instances testFiltered = Filter.useFilter(test, filter);
    System.out.println(testFiltered.instance(0));
    Instance tfidf = builder.vectorizeInstance(test.instance(0));
    System.out.println(tfidf);
    // serialize
    SerializationHelper.write("/some/where/filter.ser", filter);
    SerializationHelper.write("/some/where/dictionary.ser", filter.getDictionary());
    // deserialize
    StringToWordVectorExposed filter2 = (StringToWordVectorExposed) SerializationHelper.read("/some/where/filter.ser");
    DictionaryBuilder builder2 = (DictionaryBuilder) SerializationHelper.read("/some/where/dictionary.ser");
    // re-apply
    testFiltered = Filter.useFilter(test, filter2);
    System.out.println(testFiltered.instance(0));
    tfidf = builder2.vectorizeInstance(test.instance(0));
    System.out.println(tfidf);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer! Based on that, I though I could serialize and save to disk the ```weka.core.DictionaryBuilder``` object that is created under the hood so when I need to vectorize a new ```weka.core.Instance``` I would load and deserialize it... BUT... although the DictionaryBuilder class does implement ```Serializable``` it won't serialize as ```SerializationUtils.serialize(super.m_dictionaryBuilder)``` keeps giving me ```java.io.NotSerializableException``` :-(

Comment: In case someone is wondering... I had to extend the ```StringToWordVector``` class since the ```saveDictionaryInBinaryFormTipText()``` function does nothing but returning a message... so I did an Overriding function serializing and writing DictionaryBuilder Object to disk.... but... with no success...

Comment: I added an explicit example with my **Edit 1**.

Comment: Thanks sincerely for your new answer... Unfortunately neither the StringToWordVector nor the DictionaryBuilder objects can be serialized... It keeps throwing me NotSerializableException...

Comment: What version of Weka are using? The StringToWordVector has always been serializable. Did you modify the code base?

Comment: The above code (forgot to remove the ADAMS Environment import originally) works with vanilla Weka 3.9.6. If you use your own stemmers, tokenizers, etc, then make sure that these are serializable first.

Comment: You are totally right. What I was doing wrong was using a Stemmer of mine that cannot be serialized... Therefore the whole StringToWordVector could not be serialized. When switched it to LovinsStemmer (which BTW does not work good with greek language but I will see what I can do with that...) it serialized ok. Thanks again.

Comment: As long as your stemmer class implements the `java.io.Serializable` and all of its member variables are serializable, it should be fine. You can test your stemmer using Weka's [SerializationHelper](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/SerializationHelper.html) class.